# can I use DESC oracle function to display just the column name?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know how to do this using SELECT but how can I do this using DESC?

Comment: Why do you want this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.  These [are the only options available](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm) regarding `DESC`/`DESCRIBE`:

- LINESIZE
- DEPTH
- INDENT
- LINE

Of those, `DEPTH` would be the most likely - but all it does is lookup children objects & present their attributes in the list.